# Is it possible to be enrolled into a PhD programme in electrical engineering with an integrated UK masters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, united-kingdom

I'm an undergraduate in London South Bank University. After I finish my four year integrated master programme, can I directly apply for a 3 year PhD programme in the UK or Europe? Likewise, if I apply for PhD programme in the US, can I skip a year or more from a five-year US PhD program?

Some notes: I'm doing research in electrical engineering. My GPA is 3.9 on a 4-point scale.

Comment: I don't know how things work in EE departments, but based on how things work in UK maths departments, one could certainly enrol on a 3-year PhD (in maths, in the UK) having just completed an integrated masters (in maths). However, particular EE departments in particular universities may have certain preferences -- it is worth trying to contact the departments you are interested in applying to

Comment: Based on my subjective experience and what I've seen of friends: You can apply and be accepted to a PhD in the UK with an integrated masters (friends). You can apply and be accepted to a PhD in Europe (France - me) with an integrated masters - as long as you've written a dissertation during your final year. You can apply and be accepted to a PhD in the US with an integrated Masters (friend), but you can't skip any of the prereqs. But this is university dependent and overly-broad and it's a question for your admissions officer(s) at the prospective university (or universities).

Comment: @ la femme cosmique first thanks for your reply , secondly did you mean that I would be accepted in us phd for 5 years or will I be able to skip a year or 2 from the 5 year phd us program due to having an integrated masters i had family circumstances that already made me postpone one year of my undergrad studies so i want to hurry up .

Comment: @h.hamid based on what I've seen, you would be admitted to a PhD programme in the US in the same fashion as any US student finishing a bachelors degree would, you would still need to take classes / quals. Bear in mind that a US BSc is 4 years and a IM is 4 years. This is how it is viewed (even though the IM is much much more specialised). However this is based on a friend's experience. This is really a question for your admissions officer in the US and will likely change between universities. If you want a 'faster' PhD I urge the European route, which is what I did, so I may be biased.

Comment: full disclosure: my background is physics/astrophysics and my friends were astrophysics/experimental physics. EU normally requires 5 years total education (3 year license and 2 years master) but I had zero problems being admitted with a UK MPhys because I provided my dissertation. I am a PhD student in France presently, My friend who went to the US went to Denver, CO. YMMV for other countries/universities. 

Getting prerequisites dropped in the US is a tough business, most admission officials want to avoid it.

Comment: You will have zero trouble being admitted to a PhD programme in the UK with an IM. Your only trouble will be funding if you are non-UK or non-EU. Your decision should be based on what you want to do afterward. If you want an academic TT job in the states, you almost definitely should do your PhD in the US. If not, go to Europe or UK.

Comment: @ la femme cosmique thanks again for your reply. actually im an Egyptian and I want to avoid funds and if possible get a fellowship so the uk route is blocked for me . but aren't there any exceptions made in the us for special students im asking if i was able to prove to them that i master the first two years courses maybe by taking there exams before i enter.

Comment: im asking this because my older brother had just a pure math bs and got exempted from masters and was allowed to start phd directly in central euroean university Budapest by proving to them through recommendation letters that he mastered the master courses im already going to have an integrated masters

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Can you please turn your comments into an answer so that I can vote for it?